# Pandas output in Scimax

Tags: org-mode, org-babel

In Scimax, when I evaluate a pandas DataFrame (DF) in an Ipython block,

```
#+BEGIN_SRC ipython
data = [
    ['a', 'foo', 'bar'],
    ['FOO', 'and', 'BAR']
]
pd.DataFrame(data)
#+END_SRC
```

It produces both a plain text representation of the DF as well as a
[pop-up html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GLcwZ.png).

I was wondering how I could disable this web page pop-up and possibly replace it with an inline image of the DF?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a tricky issue. The formatting is controlled by functions that are set in `ob-ipython-mime-formatters`. The html formatting is controlled by `ob-ipython-format-text/html`. The issue is that the output is raw html, which is very inconvenient in an org-file, especially when it is very long.

`ob-ipython-preview-html` was an approach to put an overlay on the html blocks. How that is done is in  `ob-ipython-html-font-lock`.

To get what you want, you should create a function like `ob-ipython-format-text/html` that would create a temp html file, run the html to image program, save it and put a link to the image that would show it. I have had mixed luck converting html to images. A reasonable alternative might be to just save the html to a file, and link to it.

Some ways to suppress the html output are:

Use `:display text/plain` in the src block header.

or write your own formatter like this:

```
(defun my-format-html (_file _value)
 "")

(setf (cdr (assoc 'text/html ob-ipython-mime-formatters)) 'my-format-html)
```

I am transitioning away from ob-ipython in scimax, and moving towards emacs-jupyter.

Comment: How can I find documentation on the functions \ variables you mention? I tried looking in the built in docs, and in `ob-ipython.el`,  nothing there. Would it be simpler to just disable the html output altogether, and leave just plain text?

Comment: If you type C-h v, and then the name of the variable, or C-h f and the name of the function, it will show you documentation on them.

Comment: They are defined  in scimax-org-babel-ipython-upstream.el.

I updated the answer with some ways to disable it.

Answer (score 1):

I don't use Scimax.

I had a look at the codebase and I suspect that adding the following to your `init.el` will fix it:

`(setq ob-ipython-preview-html nil)`

Comment: Thanks @aadcg, but that didn't work. I tried evaluating it locally in the file as well as adding to init.el. Regarding the later, I'm not sure how Scimax is configured so it might be that this option is configured in a different file? But I'm guessing it should have worked after evaluating locally.